# Safari 10/Sierra - `Promise.all` not working...for me?

Tags: javascript, safari

Within the native Promises,

`Promise.all([ Promise.resolve() ]).then(resp => console.log('hiya!'));`

does not log anything for me. Safari Version 10.0 (12602.1.50.0.10). I have checked with other people running the same setup, and they are getting the log. Other than logging a bug (which is my next step), is there anybody with any other insight as to why this might be happening? It's not non-native Promises screwing things up. This is on any page.

Edit:

Turns out it might be the plain old `Promise.resolve`.

`Promise.resolve().then(resp => console.log('hiya!'))`

doesn't work, either. But then again, neither does

`Promise.all([ 1, 2, 3 ]).then(resp => console.log('hiya!'))`.

must be the entire promise engine...

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue here

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. Like I said you're not the first. Any thoughts as to _why_, though?

Comment: You can try clearing your cache or a restart?

Comment: I've done a few of those.

Comment: Can you confirm if this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vm9pkhus/) doesn't work for you?

Comment: It didn't last night, but it does now. Turns out my comp needed a full restart. I had to close all the apps and then restart, then reopen the apps. Even a move from dev beta sierra to commercial sierra wasn't enough. I've had a few of those thing happen before, where something was broken until I closed the app and restarted with the app closed.